# NFS delta update

Tags: nfs

In trying to set up a highly custom periodic folder synchronization setup for synching a directory on an XP machine to an NFS export on a remote (debian) box, I've become... contemplative, and am second guessing myself (partially because I'm more a developer than a systems guy, and you don't know what you don't know, you know?).

The network is assumed to be *highly* unreliable, and network bandwidth is at a premium and these files can be quite large.  I have zero control over the export or the remote machine hosting it (so I can't set up some sort of custom daemon there), but I can do as much computation on the XP side as I want to.

The solution I came up with was to compare file size ( L bytes locally, R bytes remotely), and only append transmit (L-R) bytes to each file (i.e., to send only the delta).

My questions are twofold:

1) I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  Is there a better, standard way that I can perform this operation reliably?  Because I'm not sure if I *really* want the answer to #2 ;)

2) If this sounds like a fine solution, what are some more off-beat edge cases, things to guard, etc.?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSync sounds like it would be your ticket. There is a cygwin binary for Windows.

First hit for "rsync windows" on Google gives you [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) .

Comment: Can you recommend a solid resource that can enable me to set up a functional system as quickly as possible?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: From the DeltaCopy manual that I quickly searched, yes, it appears that you will require an rsync daemon to run on the Debian server. It's not "custom", it's often included in the installation. Also, it can run over SSH, which is secure and often already open.

Comment: Everything I've seen talks about requiring an rsync daemon on the server side - Is that true, or does it still work without the daemon? The reason I ask is that I am almost 100% sure that the person in control of the debian machine would _NOT_ open that port or run that service.

Comment: rsync has options for running over SSL, that will start the remote rsync instance.  This is the way I have always run it to remote servers.  See the documentation for -e option.

Comment: @BillThor - I think that only applies to native Unix RSync, not to DeltaCopy. At least according to my quick perusal of the documentation for it.

Comment: @BillThor - unfortunately, it still requires running something on the remote box that the admin of that box probably won't want me to.  @mfinni - yes, Having just set up a mock system to test that, DeltaCopy doesn't seem to want to interact with systems that aren't running rsyncd.  I had heard of rsync before today, I don't know why I had ruled it out.  Since you inspired me to give it another go, though, I'll award you this one.  Hopefully that admin won't reject my request ;p

Comment: @Nate - delta copy supports ssh and -e. Search 'deltacopy ssh' in google.  RSync is often installed on Unix, and if not can be installed locally.